# How to put a superscript right after a subscript that is not for the subscript

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, subscript, superscript

I am trying to make a label that has a superscript right after a subscript but I don't want the superscript as part of the subscript.

I have tried and either got the superscript as part of the subscript or just right above the subscript after the letter the subscript is after.

This is what I have for the x-axis but I want the `-1` as a regular superscript after the subscript `"seawater"`, not over it.

```r
labs(, x= expression("Incurrent matter "~(mu~mol*" L"[seawater]^{-1}))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, gear)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(x = expression("Incurrent matter"~(mu~mol*"L"[seawater]*""^{-1})))
```